# xmlstarlet output with quotes

Tags: xml, makefile, xmlstarlet

I have a list of `XPath` queries modeled in an `XML` file as follows (`querylist.xml`) :

```
<queries>
    <query id="1" project="docbook" xpath=".//@id|.//@xml:id"/> 
    <query id="2" project="docbook" xpath="descendant::h:span[@data-type='footnote']"/>
</queries>
```

And I am using xmlstarlet in makefile to list and run the xpath queries on files with the same `project` attribute name, using for example:

Update-Makefile content:

```
QUERYLIST0 = $(shell xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//query[@project='docbook']/@id" -v "concat(., ' ')"  querylist.xml)
QUERYLIST1 = $(shell xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//query[@project='docbook']/@xpath" -v "concat(., ' ')"  querylist.xml)

echoq:
    @echo $(QUERYLIST0)
    @echo $(QUERYLIST1)
```

But I am unable to list the `xpath` attribute queries whenever it has single quotes(ex: `'footnote'`), How can I keep the attribute value as is, even when containing single quotes?

The output should be a list separated by a space:

```
.//@id|.//@xml:id descendant::h:span[@data-type='footnote']
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for your xmlstarlet command to your question (no comment here).

Comment: @Cyrus I updated the xmlstarlet command and the output

Answer (score 1):

I checked your command on the bash shell as well as in a bash script. It worked in both cases - with the slight modification of omitting the "shell" part after the `$(...`:

1. On command line:

   ```
   xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//query[@project='docbook']/@xpath" -v "concat(.,' ')"  querylist.xml
   ```

   does work.
2. And on the `bash` shell the script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   RES=$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//query[@project='docbook']/@xpath" -v "concat(.,' ')"  querylist.xml)
   echo $RES
   ```

   does work, too.

In both cases the result is

```
.//@id|.//@xml:id descendant::h:span[@data-type='footnote']
```

as desired.

Comment: Yes in the shell it working just fine, the problem is when calling it from the makefile, the "shell" part is to be used when in a makefile

Comment: I updated to question with the makefile content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <queries>
      <query id="1" project="docbook" xpath=".//@id|.//@xml:id"/>
      <query id="2" project="docbook" xpath="descendant::h:span[@data-type='footnote']"/>
    </queries>

$ xml sel -t -m queries/query[@project='docbook'] -v @xpath -i "number(count(preceding::query[@project='docbook']))+1<number(count(./../query[@project='docbook']))" -o " " -b file.xml


.//@id|.//@xml:id descendant::h:span[@data-type='footnote']
```